# Facebook API - Get friends name by their ID

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I have a query that gives me list of friends ID's:

```
'SELECT owner FROM photo WHERE object_id IN (SELECT object_id FROM photo_tag WHERE subject=me())'
```

I want to get the names of those ID's, i tried doing it with :

```
var frndTagNames = new Array();

for (var j=0;j<frndTagIds.fql_result_set.length;j++)

{
    FB.api('/'+frndTagIds.fql_result_set[j].owner+'', function(frnds) {
    frndTagNames[j] = frnds.name;
});
}   
console.log(frndTagNames);
```

The problem is that i can't the "frndTagNames" Array outside the FB.api Scope.

**BTW, this whole code is inside another FB.api code**

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

frndTagNames should be available within the callback function.  What type of response are you getting (e.g. an error of some kind)? Try adding console.log(response) to the callback function.

For example, I can define an array and assign a value to it within the a callback function like so:

```
var foo = new Array();

FB.api('/me/', function(resp) { foo[0]=resp.name });

console.log(foo[0])
"Brian Ledsworth"
```

Nested blocks example (preserve context of 'this').  Assign this to _that, then use _that.frndTagNames

```
var _that = this;
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  if (response.status === 'connected') {
    FB.api('/me/friends', function(response) {
      if(response && response.data) {
        for(i=0;i<response.data.length;i++) {
          _that.friendsFacebookColl.add(response.data[i]);
        }
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work, i can't use the variable inside the fb.api scope outside of it ... which it's odd because it like another other GLOBAL variable ..

Any other ideas ?

Comment: Ah!  Just noticed your BTW comment that this runs inside another FB.api call.  Therefore, 'this' has changed context.  See edited answer....